# EditorFor ICollection and named Template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates, editorfor, icollection

i am new to MVC 5 and ASP.NET, EF6 and now i have a Problem with a named EditorTemplate.

My Model looks like this:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int pid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Filter> Filters{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Filter
{
    public bool isRemoveable { get; set; }
}
```

And i have a EditorTemplate called FiltersCustomEditor, thats look like this:

```
@model IList<Filter>

@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => @Model[i].isRemoveable)
```

My Problem is now that in my Product View i can´t call:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filters, "FiltersCustomEditor")
```

I get this error:

> The model element that has been passed to the dictionary , is of type "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[Filter]".
>   However, this dictionary requires a model item of type "System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Filter]".]

So i tried to call it like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filters.ToList(), "FiltersCustomEditor")
```

And get this error:

> Templates can only be used with field access , property access , one-dimensional array indices or custom Indexerausdrücken with a single parameter .

If i convert the ICollection in my Model to a List it works perfect. But this is a generated class from Entity Framework so a change here breaks the EF functionality.

I think this is a special problem for named Templates. Because if i make a Default EditorTemplate for a Single Filter called Filter.cshtml and calling

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filters)
```

The ICollection is handled internaly very well and the EditorFor calls the Template for each Object in the List.

But their must be a solution for this Problem. The Only thing that works is to change the Template to

```
@model ICollection<Filter>

@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => @Model.ToList()[i].isRemoveable)
```

And call it like this

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filters, "FiltersCustomEditor")
```

But i think this is realy a weak solution, specialy for performance, if every field must convert the ICollection to a List before access.

So is their a way to workaround or am i missing something?

Comment: Your property is `ICollection<Filter>` but your view is `@model IList<Filter>`. They are not the same thing. You need to change one of the other. But the correct approach is to name your template `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Filter.cshtml` and just use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filters)` where the template is `@model Filter` and contains `EditorFor(m =>m.isRemoveable)`

Comment: Yes this works, but what if i want a Custom Editor for a List of Filters? And specialy if i want more than one Editor for Filter? Is there a way to give the linq expression of EditorFor the ICollection as a List?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment - if the template is named to match the model and has `@model Filter` and `@EditorFor(m =>m.isRemoveable)` then it **is** a template that can be used to render a collection (by using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filters)` in the main view). That's how editor templates are designed to work. If you want multiple filters your can add more specific ones in `Views/YourController/EditorTemplates/Filter.cshtm` so that you can have a different template for each controller

Comment: And no, you cannot pass `ICollection<T>` to something expecting `IList<T>` or vice versa

Comment: ah this is a very good point: Views/YourController/EditorTemplates/Filter.cshtm.
I didn´t know that i have EditorTemplates per Controller, i thought they must always be Shared. Then the Approach with the Single Element Template suits my needs. Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, by default if you use `EditorFor()` on a property which as a complex object of collection of complex objects, the method will first search `/Views/YourController/EditorTemplates`. If one is not found ot will then search `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates. And finally if one if not found it will use the built in default template(s) based on your model properties. Feel free to add your own answer and accept it, but if not I wlll add one in the morning

Answer (score 1):

Your passing `ICollection<Filter>` to the template, but the model in the template is `IList<Filter>`, hence the error (`ICollection<T>` is not `IList<T>`). However your approach is not correct. The `EditorFor()` method accepts `IEnumerable<T>` so the code can be simplified to

In `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Filter.cshtml` (note the template must be named the same as the name of the class)

```
@model yourAssembly.Filter
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.isRemoveable)
.... // add any other properties, labels etc of Filter
```

and then in the main view it is simply

```
@model yourAssembly.Product
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  ....
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filters)
}
```

The `EditorFor()` method will correctly generate the html for each item in your collection based on the template (no loops, no passing collections etc.)

Side note: Further to you comments, you can also place specific `EditorTemplates` related to each controller in the `/Views/YourControllerName/EditorTemplates` folder. By default, the `EditorFor()` method will first search `/Views/YourController/EditorTemplates`. If one is not found it will then search `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`. And finally if one is not found it will use the built in default template(s) based on your model properties.